# How do I make Palindrome function reverse more than one word

Tags: c++, palindrome

My palindrome function's supposed to find a word (or more than one word) in string, compare it with a bunch of other strings in the container, and if it finds one that's the same, reverse it, and stick them together. E.g. `palindrome -> palindromeemordnilap`, or if it's a more than one word: `two words > two wordssdrow owt`.

Mine's working for only one word, and also, for some reason, fails to correctly reverse the last one in the sentence. What should I, if even possible, change to accomplish the above?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

typedef std::vector<std::string> StringVektor;

std::string ReverseString(std::string s1)
{
    std::string to_return(s1);
    char temp(0);

    for (int i(0); i < vrati.size() / 2; i++) 
    {
        temp = to_return.at(i);
        to_return.at(i) = to_return.at(to_return.length() - 1 - i);
        to_return.at(to_return.length() - 1 - i) = temp;
    }

    return to_return;
}

std::string CreatePalindrome(String s, StringVektor v)
{
    std::string compare;

    for (int i(0); i < s.size(); i++)
    {
        if (s.at(i) != ' ') 
            compare += s.at(i);

        if (s.at(i) == ' ' || i == s.length() - 1)
        {
            for (int j(0); j < v.size(); j++)
            {
                if (compare == v.at(j))
                {
                    std::string put_in;
                    put_in = ReverseString(v.at(j));
                    s.insert(i, put_in);
                }
            }

            compare.clear();
        }
    }

    std::string to_return;
    to_return = s;

    return to_return;
}

int main ()
{
    std::string sentence, phrase;
    StringVektor v1;

    std::cout << "Enter your sentence: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, sentence);
    std::cout << "Enter phrases: ";

    for ( ;;) 
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, phrase);

        if(!fraza.empty()) 
            v1.push_back(phrase);

        if(std::cin.peek() == '\n') 
            break;
    }

    std::cout << "Your sentence after the transformation: " << 
                 CreatePalindrome(sentence, v1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You use `std::cout` but `std::string` requires its own `typedef`? Why? Also, give you code some room to breath, we're not charged by the line here....

Comment: @Drise Just a habit.

Comment: Have you used a debugger? Might help you figure out where an assumption is untrue.

Comment: Try stepping through with a debugger.   The logic of extracting a word, and then clearing word, is flawed.

Comment: As ugly as `std::string` might look to you, `String` is just downright confusing to someone who isn't familiar with your code, so going with the boring, if seemingly ugly `std::string` is almost always better. You'll get used to the prefix over time, it'll become expected, even desirable for reasons of clarity.

Comment: @tadman I've seen (in production code no less) that `String` was some amalgam of `std::string`, Qt's `QString`, and some Boost algorithms. It was a nightmare to work with as a newcomer, because there was no standard convention on when just reverting to using one of the "base" string types was acceptable. So now we had `std::string`, `QString`, and `String`s everywhere.

Comment: I'd also argue that `typedef std::vector<std::string> Vektor;` should at least be named `StringVektor` if that is the desired convention. As it stands, it just looks like it would refer to `typedef std::vector Vektor;`, but I'm becoming pedantic, and starting to stray off topic.

Comment: You could simply store each word in a container and print out the contents of the container in reverse order.  Or store in a LIFO container such as a `std::stack` and pop off each element

Comment: Corrected all `String` and `Vektor` typedefs. Hope that helps.

Comment: Been trying for an hour now, haven't had any luck making it work. Suggestions anybody?

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger and create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Questions asking for debugging help without trying with the debugger or minimal code is not really received well here. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: @Rose I see you still don't have an answer. Do you have an example input that works and one that fails?

Comment: @FeiXiang I did use a debugger, and everything seemed to work fine.

Comment: @Drise Okay, here's an example when it works, https://prnt.sc/iythh9, and when when it doesn't, https://prnt.sc/iytho7. Part before the sentences basically means "Enter your sentence". As you can see, the last word's improperly reversed, compared to the correct example.

Comment: Debug your code section by section. For example, test the `ReverseString` function all by itself. Then test the `CreatePalindrome` function.

Comment: In this case, the problem is in the line `if (s.at(i) == ' ' || i == s.length() - 1)`. Usually, when the condition is true, you're looking at the space after a word. However, at the end of the string, you're looking at the last character of a word instead of the character after the word. This causes the insertion to happen one character to the left of where it's supposed to be. Instead of checking for the end of the string, add a space to the end of the string at the start of the function if there isn't already one.